# Could I follow a MySQLi tutorial using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There is a tutorial I'd like to follow which has some great reviews. The only problem being it makes use of MySQLi instead of MySQL. I only have access to MySQL.

Are there big enough differences to warrant looking for a straight PHP-MySQL tutorial or is it worth just going with this one and making changes myself?

I would say I am a 'beginner' with both PHP and MySQL, but can find my way around the code fine, apply CRUD etc so not completely new.

Comment: If you add a link to the tutorial we can give you more specific pointers about what would have to be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLi is PHP's "improved" MySQL driver. Meaning it will take full advantage of MySQL servers version higher than 4.1.3.

Then underlaying MySQL server would be the same, using the old MySQL interface or the newer MySQLi, so everthing should remain valid if you are following a MySQL tutorial on a MySQLi interface.

In your case, you should pay attention to MySQLi only stuff since they won't be avaliable to you.

Quote from the [official website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php):

> What is PHP's mysqli Extension?
>
> The mysqli extension, or as it is
>   sometimes known, the MySQL improved
>   extension, was developed to take
>   advantage of new features found in
>   MySQL systems versions 4.1.3 and
>   newer. The mysqli extension is
>   included with PHP versions 5 and
>   later.
>
> The mysqli extension has a number of
>   benefits, the key enhancements over
>   the mysql extension being:
>
> Object-oriented interface
>
> Support for Prepared Statements
>
> Support for Multiple Statements
>
> Support for Transactions
>
> Enhanced debugging capabilities
>
> Embedded server support

Comment: There are some things that were added with mysqli that are not in mysql. Prepared statements is one of them.

Comment: No problem. Seeing that you are new to the site, don't forget to accept the most useful answer and upvote other useful answers too (being mine or not). Happy coding!

Comment: @datasage you are right. I thought he was following a MySQL tutorial on a MySQLi interface, corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too hard to make the necessary adjustments.  If you look at PHP's [MySQL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) vs the [MySQLi functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) functions the main difference is that MySQLi is an object-oriented interface. Converting back to the regular MySQL functions is usually quite easy, for example: `$rs->affected_rows` becomes `mysql_affected_rows($rs)`.

As @hexa pointed out, there are a couple things in MySQLi that the old interface doesn't support, such as prepared queries.  If the tutorial involves those, it's not that hard to convert them to regular queries, it's just a bit of a hassle.